# Multiple language parser generator

Tags: parsing, parser-generator

Is there a parser generator that can take a single grammar and create a parser in both c# and javascript?

I've tried using ANTLR, but I have yet to get it into Visual Studio (lackluster/outdated documentation and packages).

The end goal is that I can manage a single grammar (for a subset of SQL; specifically select statements and a few new keywords specific to my problem domain) but generate two parsers (c#/javascript).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a parser generator that can take a single grammar and create a parser in both c# and javascript?

The only one I am aware of is ANTLR. Note that ANTLR will not generate both a JavaScript- and C# based parser in one go though. You will have to change (at least) one option in the grammar and invoke `org.antlr.Tool` to generate a parser for your other target language.

> I've tried using ANTLR, but I have yet to get it into Visual Studio

Then don't use Visual Studio, but use your favorite text editor (and use `org.antlr.Tool` from the console), or ANTLRWorks.

Answer (score 1):

There's [canopy](http://canopy.jcoglan.com/), which targets javascript, ruby, java, and python from PEG

Answer (score 0):

My AGL parser builder is written in Kotlin common, so it can be used on any Kotlin target (JVM, JavaScript, native code, etc).

https://medium.com/@dr.david.h.akehurst/a-kotlin-multi-platform-parser-usable-from-a-jvm-or-javascript-59e870832a79

Unfortunately, Kotlin does not yet target .net....but maybe it will come in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[docopt](http://docopt.org/) let you describe your help message in a string respecting some common convention and that's how all commands, options and arguments will be defined.

Docopt has many official implementations: python, bash, C#, rust, ruby, C++, Go, R, Julia, Nim, Hashkell, PHP, C, F#, CoffeeScript, Swift, Scala, D, Java, Clojure, Tcl, Lua